# Testflight won't install iphone app on iPad that doesn't have GPS built-in

Tags: ios, ipad, gps, testflight

I have a person who wants to install my iPhone app via Testflight on an iPad Air.  Specs:

```
Device Information:
Device: iPad4,1
iOS Version: 10.3.2
Language: en-US (English (United States))
Carrier: N/A
Timezone: PDT
Architecture: N/A
Connection Status: WiFi
Paired Apple Watch: N/A
```

They are getting an error "This build incompatible with your device. Requires 9.1 or later".  I assume this is because their iPad doesn't have built-in GPS.  However, this person stated they have enhanced location capability through an external GPS receiver which provides 10-foot accuracy.

I've installed this app on several iPads having GPS, so incompatibility is likely the GPS features of the app.  I've also made a build of the app targeting the exact version of iOS 10.3.

Does anyone have experience with this and a way to get past this without requiring a version of the app without GPS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app requires the presence of GPS (or AGPS) hardware when tracking locations and you specifically mentioned `gps` capability, then your app won't  install on the devices without GPS.

You can remove this key.

1. Go to `Info.plist`
2. Look for the key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` (*Required device capabilities*) and remove the key `gps` from the list.

**Note:** I don't think external GPS will help is this case for app installation.